# sql create sequence number in subset - apache derby

Tags: sql, derby, window-functions

Able to generate Sequence number using the following query

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqno AS integer
START WITH 1;

SELECT t1.*,
   (NEXT VALUE
    FOR seqno) AS seqno
FROM
  (SELECT l.TRANSACTION_ID,
      l.HSN
   FROM RWLINEITEM l
   WHERE l.TRANSACTION_ID IN ('CS610-20-10003','CS610-20-10002')
   GROUP BY l.TRANSACTION_ID,l.HSN) t1
```

this gives result

[image: Sql Output]

The requirement is to generate sequence number by Transaction and HSN for example

[image: Expected result]

Is there any way to arrive this result. Using derby-10.13.1.1

Comment: As per this question answer, looks no soulution for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325930/feature-not-implemented-window-order-by

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Derby does not fully support standard window function `row_number()`.

A typical approach to emulate this is to use a subquery that counts how many rows have the same `transaction_id` and a smaller `hsn`, like so:

```
select 
    transaction_id, 
    hsn, 
    1 + coalesce(
        (
            select count(*) 
            from rwlineitem l1 
            where l1.transaction_id = l.transaction_id and l1.hsn < l.hsn
        ),
        0
    ) seqno 
from rwlineitem l
where transaction_id in ('CS610-20-10003','CS610-20-10002')
order by transaction_id, hsn
```

Note that if there are duplicates `(transaction_id, hsn)` tuples, they would get the same `seqno`. This is similar to how window function `rank()` works. If you want a unique number, then you can try and add another random sorting criteria:

```
select 
    transaction_id, 
    hsn, 
    1 + coalesce(
        (
            select count(*) 
            from rwlineitem l1 
            where 
                l1.transaction_id = l.transaction_id 
                and (
                    l1.hsn < l.hsn 
                    or (l1.hsn = l.hsn and random() < 0.5)
                )
        ),
        0
    ) seqno 
from rwlineitem l
where transaction_id in ('CS610-20-10003','CS610-20-10002')
order by transaction_id, hsn
```

Comment: @vels4j: I updated my answer with a solution that does not use window functions.

Comment: didnt work, thanks for your effort, I will share you a sql fiddle. looking some online tools with derby

Comment: @vels4j: what do you mean by did not work? Are you getting, an error (whic one)? Or maybe wrong results?

Comment: @vels4j: that seems pretty close to what you want. I just added an `order by` clause to the query.

Comment: No luck
TRANSACTION_ID HSN SEQNO
CS610-20-10003 3004 1
CS610-20-10003 3004 1
CS610-20-10003 3304 3
CS610-20-10003 3401 4

Comment: @vels4j: yes, because these two records have the same transaction_id and hsn, so they get the same row number. Do you have another column that can be used to break the ties?

Comment: added table schema here https://ibb.co/Wv4VXwZ line item will have many txnids and many hsn. Idea is to group txnId wise, hsnWise and add seq number.

Comment: @vels4j: when two records have the same `transaction_id` and `hsn`, how do you decide which one is ranked first? In this situation, which column should be use to break the tie?

Comment: when you group it by transaction_id and hsn you will get unique then need to asssign seq number

Comment: @vels4j: I added another query to my answer.

Comment: no luck, Result of your last query https://ibb.co/MB8pJVF , many thanks for your all the effort